# How using jQuery I can find the forms that doesn't have/contain input tag inside them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html:

```
<form>
 ..
 <input>
 ..
</form>

<form>
 ..
 <p></p>
 ..
</form>
```

How using jQuery I can find the forms that doesn't have/contain input tag inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
// find all <form> elements, and then filter that
// collection:
$('form').filter(function(){

  // we use find() to find the <input>
  // elements within the current <form>, and
  // if that count is 0 (there are no <input>
  // elements) we return the current <form> and
  // keep it in the collection:
  return $(this).find('input').length === 0;
})
```

```js
$('form').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('input').length === 0;
}).addClass('hasNoInput');
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 80vw;
}

.hasNoInput {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <label>Here's an &lt;input&gt; element:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</form>
```

With JavaScript:

```
// we use the spread (...) operator with an Array
// literal to convert the NodeList returned by
// document.querySelectorAll() to an Array, and
// then use Array.prototype.filter() to filter
// that Array of Nodes:
[...document.querySelectorAll('form')].filter(
  // we use an Arrow function to pass the current
  // <form> element-node into the function, and we
  // retain <form> elements for which el.querySelector
  // (Element.prototype.querySelector) returns a null
  // (or any other falsey value):
  (el) => !el.querySelector('input')
);
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('form')].filter(
  (el) => !el.querySelector('input')
).forEach(
  (el) => el.classList.add('hasNoInput')
);
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 80vw;
}

.hasNoInput {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <label>Here's an &lt;input&gt; element:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</form>
```

In the event that the use-case requires you to support older browsers then the use of `[...document.querySelectorAll()`] can be replaced by alternate methods, such as:

```
// here we use Array.from() to convert the NodeList
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() to an Array,
// and then use Array.prototype.filter() to filter
// that Array of Nodes:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).filter(
  // we use an Arrow function to pass the current
  // <form> element-node into the function, and we
  // retain <form> elements for which el.querySelector
  // (Element.prototype.querySelector) returns a null
  // (or any other falsey value):
  (el) => !el.querySelector('input')
);
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).filter(
  (el) => !el.querySelector('input')
).forEach(
  (el) => el.classList.add('hasNoInput')
);
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 80vw;
}

.hasNoInput {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <label>Here's an &lt;input&gt; element:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</form>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter).
  - [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: you should also add the non ES6 JavaScript solution to your answer `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).filter( function(el) { return !el.querySelector('input') } );` ( I guess that should work )